# How do I test next/link (Nextjs) getting page redirect after onClick in React?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, enzyme, next.js

I want to test the page get redirected after click on div, but I dont know how, this is my code. Thank you so much

```
<div className="bellTest">
   <NextLink href="/notifications">
       <Bell />
   </NextLink>
 </div>
```

test.tsx

```
jest.mock('next/link', () => {
     return ({ children }) => {
            return children;
     };
});

describe('Test of <HeaderContainer>', () => {
    test('Test the page redirect after click', async done => {
        const wrapper = mount( <HeaderComponent /> );
        await wrapper
            .find('.bellTest')
            .at(0)
            .simulate('click');
        // expect the page getting redirect
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of mocking `next/link` you can register a spy on router events, and check if it was called.

The test will look like this:

```
import Router from 'next/router';

describe('Test of <HeaderContainer>', () => {
  const spies: any = {};

  beforeEach(() => {
    spies.routerChangeStart = jest.fn();
    Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', spies.routerChangeStart);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', spies.routerChangeStart);
  });

  test('Test the page redirect after click', async done => {
    const wrapper = mount(<HeaderComponent />);
    await wrapper
      .find('.bellTest')
      .at(0)
      .simulate('click');

    expect(spies.routerChangeStart).toHaveBeenCalledWith('expect-url-here');
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you, but `spies.routerChangeStart = jest.fn();` shows this error `Property 'routerChangeStart' does not exist on type '{}'` Can you show more detail?

Comment: See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16864#issuecomment-702069418